# Google Shopping module that use Shopping Content API v2?

Tags: google-shopping-api, google-shopping

As i believe you already know Google is retiring the Shopping Content API v1 at the end of February 2015. After this date all API requests to the Content API v1 will no longer work and our products will no longer be visible in Product Listing Ads.

My question is: Do you know any good Google Shopping module that use Shopping Content API v2?

Thank You!!!

Kind regards,

Radu

Answer (score 0):

First of all what platform are you using as this would help in advising on a plugin. also if you are worried about the api version being dropped then i would suggest creating a xml version of your feed and passing your products through that way i always find this is the better option